# Multiplayer lobbies in Halo MCC

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

Every time I play multiplayer for the Master Chief Collection, I finish the game and have to exit the lobby, and select a gamemode again. Is there any way around this, or is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the multiplayer in the game is designed to work, yes. Why 343i did it this way is up to them.